# Detect a string containing pipe and append

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to write regex rules for preg_replace and need to append something to a sub string that contains at least one | and ends in line break.

```
$str = '"as das dasd", "asrydasd|artysdad|aksda'; // no trailing "

$find = '/^\"*\|*\n$/s';

$replace = $1.'"';

$result = preg_replace($find, $replace, $str);
```

Comment: What is the desired result for your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your pattern you use an anchor to assert the start of the string. There is also no newline at the end of the string present, and no capture group `$1` that you refer to in the replacement.

Your pattern curently matches optional  double quotes, then optional pipe chars, a newline and then asserts the end of the string. That [can also match](https://regex101.com/r/8NXE6R/1) an  empty string followed by a newline.

If you only want to make sure that the string starts with a double quote and contains at least a single pipe char:

```
^"[^|\r\n]*\|.*\n$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1K51PT/1)

Looking at the comment in the code, if you want to match a pipe between an inclosed double quote till the end of the string:

```
"[^"|\r\n]*\|[^"\r\n]*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OXdfn1/1/)

Replace with the whole match `$0"`